# How to write a method that accepts an array of type x and another variable with the same type as the array

Tags: java, generics

I would like to write a generic method that accepts an array and something else. Each of which could be whatever type, but they must be the same. I tried this, but I could still input anything into the method.

```
public static <T> boolean arrayContains(T[] array, T object){
    return Arrays.asList(array).contains(object);
}
```

I can call this method with `arrayContains(new String[]{"stuff"}, new Pig())` but I only want it to accept `arrayContains(new String[]{"stuff"}, "more stuff")`

Comment: What about `arrayContains( T object, T[] array)`?

Comment: Problem is that in your case `T` become `Object`. Don't see any solution except explicitly specialize type.

Comment: In this case, `arrayContains`, it doesn't really matter. It will just return false, because a `String[]` cannot contain a `Pig`. But anyways, it's an `Object` in that case as stated above.

Comment: That is my problem, I accidentally pass the wrong type for the second argument and it never returns true, nor does the compiler catch it. I passed an array of Packages and then a String of the package and then I could not figure out what was wrong. I then figured it out and I decided to write my own method for this so I wouldn't have the same problem again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing.

```
public static boolean arrayContains(Object[] array, Object object) {
        if (array.getClass().getComponentType() != object.getClass()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Type of array and object are not equal! " + array.getClass().getComponentType().getName() + " != " + object.getClass().getName()); //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$
        }
        return Arrays.asList(array).contains(object);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to do is tricky because any array (except an array of primitives) is an `Object[]`, so as you have noticed, the method will always accept any array and any object.

One way around this could be to pass an explicit `Class` object, like this

```
public static <T> boolean arrayContains(T[] array, T object, Class<T> clazz)
```

Then you could write

```
arrayContains(new String[]{"stuff"}, "more stuff", String.class)
```

but not

```
arrayContains(new String[]{"stuff"}, new Pig(), String.class)
```

Comment: I don't want to do this because it just adds another argument that takes up time.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

Or put another way, *any* array and *any* reference already satisfy your requirement, "array of type x and another varable with the same type as the array", because *any* array is an "array of type `Object`", and *any* reference is of the same type (`Object`).

What you want serves no *type-safety* purpose. Consider, hypothetically, that there were a language feature to do what you want. It can only operate on the compile-time types of the expressions of the arguments. But someone can always do this:

```
Object[] foo = anyArrayExpression;
Object bar = anyReferenceExpression;
arrayContains(foo, bar);
```

or

```
arrayContains((Object[])anyArrayExpression, (Object)anyReferenceExpression);
```

(and, by the way, neither of these are doing anything fishy or unsafe. An upcast is always 100% safe and legit operation in Java.)

So any array and any reference can always be passed to your function anyway, and your function always needs to handle the actual objects being any type of array and any type object anyway. So your feature achieves nothing.

Even if you restrict it to be subtypes of some type `X`, and your function only takes `X[]` and `X`, it can still always be the case that the *actual runtime class* of the objects pointed to by the references passed in are `Y[]` and `Z`, where `Y` and `Z` are unrelated subtypes of `X`. This is just a fact of how the Java type system works. So your function will always have to deal with the runtime component type of the array being potentially unrelated to the runtime class of the other object, no matter how you do it. (The only exception would be if `X` were final, so it has no subclasses, but then your restriction would be meaningless because it would be trivially always true.)

Answer (score 0):

What about next?

```
public static <A, E extends A> boolean arrayContains(A[] array, E object){
    return Arrays.asList(array).contains(object);
}
```

In this case the type of the second argument must extend (or be the same as) the type of the array's elements.

Comment: I do want to use Java 8

Answer (score -2):

You need to provide multiple parameterized types, and then do something if they don't match.

```
public static <T, S> boolean arrayContains(T[] array, S object){
    System.out.println("array.class: " + array.getClass().getComponentType().getName());
    System.out.println("object.class: " + object.getClass().getName());
    System.out.println("array.class == object.class: " + (array.getClass().getComponentType() == object.getClass()));

    // TODO: do something if the types don't match

    return Arrays.asList(array).contains(object);
}
```

Comment: I actually ended up using this and testing the types of the object.